# Select multiple rows in a table filled by a Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, servlets

Sorry for my noob question, but I have a table filled by a servlet on my JSP page:

### Table

```xml
<table id="tableusers" class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Nom</th>
            <th>Prénom</th>
            <th>Adresse</th>
            <th>email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

### JavaScript

```js
$.get('/SRV/webUserServlet', function(responseJson) {
    if (responseJson != null) {
        var table1 = $("#tableusers");
        $.each(responseJson, function(key, value) {
            var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td class=\"center\"></td><td class=\"center\"></td><td class=\"center\"></td></tr>");
            rowNew.children().eq(0).text(value['nom']);
            rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['prenom']);
            rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['adresse']);
            rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['email']);
            rowNew.appendTo(table1);
        });
    }
});
```

Table is filled correctly but I tried multiple jQuery javascripts to select multiple rows from this table and send the result of the select lines to another servlet but unfortunately as the content is dynamic, I'm not able to make any JS script functional.

How can I select one, or multiple (or all) rows and send the selected lines (with all the columns) to a servlet ?

Answer (score 1):

When you are building the table, assign classes and / or id's to the td's that you want the values from. You can then use jquery to select off of an id, for instance, instead of selecting off of a value.

```
<table id="tableusers" class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="columns">
            <th id="col1">Nom</th>
            <th id="col2">Prénom</th>
            <th id="col3">Adresse</th>
            <th id="col4">email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>   
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then you can select the values like this:

```
$("#col1").text();
```

or like this:

```
$("tr.columns th").each(function() {
    $(this).text();
});
```

Apply the same principle to rows in the body if you are wanting those values too.

Comment: sorry but I'm a beginner in JS....how can I parse my table to retrieve which line is checked ?

Comment: Do you know ahead of time which lines / rows you want to retrieve or are you wanting all rows? If you already know which rows you want to retrieve, you should be able to change this line in your loading javascript function to include classes / id's: `var rowNew = $("<tr><td></td><td class=\"center\"></td><td class=\"center\"></td><td class=\"center\"></td></tr>");`

Comment: I don't know if I completely follow...You can select any element you using [jquery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). Might be helpful to read up on selectors. Classes or ids would be easiest, but you can select the nth line, etc as well.

Comment: Thanks TheEllis, I'll look at selectors, I just want a button to parse my table checking for the lines selected and retrieve (at least) the line number

Answer (score 0):

There is no relation with servlet, you only have a javascript problem.

Write a simple page in raw HTML, include your js code and load your page in a browser with developpers tools activated. Debug and look at which URLs are called. Once you'll have resolved this problem you will try to integrate the solution in your JSP.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried this plugin with a static table and it works fine. it seems the JS script is not working on a dymamic table.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I'm parsing my table using DOM:

```
                   var table = document.getElementById('tabletest');
               var rowLength = table.rows.length;
               for(var i=1; i<rowLength; i+=1){
                     var row = table.rows[i];
                     var cellLength = row.cells.length;
                         if(row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked==true){
                            console.log("checked");
                            console.log("cellule: "+row.cells[1].innerHTML);
                        }

                 }
```

could be interesting for people who have the same problem than me....but without JQuery.

by the way, it works only with a static table content. when I'm trying to parse the table dynamically filled by the servlet, the if statement

> if(row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked==true)

is generating an error (input undefined) but by looking at the table values, the row.cells[0] contains:

```
cell[0]: <input type="checkbox">
```

I tried with a static table with the exact table structure:

```html
<table id="tabletest" class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable datatable">
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th style="width:20px;"><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" title="Select all"></th>
  <th>Nom</th>
  <th>Prénom</th>
  <th>Adresse</th>
  <th>email</th>
 </tr>
</thead>   
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox"> </td>
 <td>john</td>
 <td>smith</td>
 <td>12 rue des laures</td>
 <td>john@tt.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox"> </td>
 <td>marcel</td>
 <td>dib</td>
 <td>13 rue des laures</td>
 <td>marcel@tt.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><input type="checkbox"> </td>
 <td>toto</td>
 <td>titi</td>
 <td>14 rue des laures</td>
 <td>steph@tt.com</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

with the following script:

```js
function checkSelectedUsers(){
             var table = document.getElementById('tabletest');
             var rowLength = table.rows.length;
             for(var i=1; i<rowLength; i+=1){
                var row = table.rows[i];
                //console.log("row: "+row.innerHTML);
                  console.log("row:"+row.innerHTML);
                  
                  console.log("cell[0]:"+row.cells[0].innerHTML);
                  console.log("cell[1]:"+row.cells[1].innerHTML);
                  if(row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].type == "checkbox")
                   console.log("Checkbox:"+row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked);
              /* if(row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('input')[0].checked==true){
        console.log("checked");
        console.log("cellule: "+row.cells[4].innerHTML);
       }*/
                  
               }            
             
            }
```

I have the following in the logs console:

```js
row:
 <td><input type="checkbox"> </td>
 <td>john</td>
 <td>smith</td>
 <td>12 rue des laures</td>
 <td>john@tt.com</td>
cell[0]:<input type="checkbox"> 
cell[1]:john
Checkbox:false
row:
 <td><input type="checkbox"> </td>
 <td>marcel</td>
 <td>dib</td>
 <td>13 rue des laures</td>
 <td>marcel@tt.com</td>
cell[0]:<input type="checkbox"> 
cell[1]:marcel
Checkbox:false
row:
 <td><input type="checkbox"> </td>
 <td>toto</td>
 <td>titi</td>
 <td>14 rue des laures</td>
 <td>steph@tt.com</td>
cell[0]:<input type="checkbox"> 
cell[1]:toto
Checkbox:false
```

so my table is parsed correctly. But if I get the same JS function  with the table generated with JQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        
              $.get('/OrdolinkSRV/webUserServlet',function(responseJson) {
               if(responseJson!=null){
                   var table1 = $("#tableusers");
                   $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) { 
                        var rowNew = $("<tr><td><input type=\"checkbox\"></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>");
                           rowNew.children().eq(1).text(value['nom']); 
                           rowNew.children().eq(2).text(value['prenom']); 
                           rowNew.children().eq(3).text(value['adresse']); 
                           rowNew.children().eq(4).text(value['email']); 
                           rowNew.appendTo(table1);
                   });

                   }
               });        
   

   });
```

I have the following error :

```
row:
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined